# Can I use Jquery UI and Jquery mobile in the same web application?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, asp.net-4.0

I want my application to be viewable properly on desktop as well as Ipad. I had a quick look at Jquery mobile and it looks very easy. My question is: I already have references to Jquery UI. Does Jquery UI interfere with Jquery mobile?

If Jquery mobile can be used on desktop based web applications also then why do we use Jquery UI. Why don't people always use Jquery Mobile so that they automatically get a view for Ios based devices also?

I am too much confused. What happens when I add reference to Jquery mobile in my website which already has Jquery UI? I don't want to spoil my live website. Any suggestions?

I am using Asp.Net 4.0 Vanilla and there are lots of gridview etc. Will jquery mobile help to show properly on desktop based applications as well as tablet based?

Comment: I'm not sure you completely understand what jQuery Mobile actually is. Have you read through the documentation?

Comment: @Blazemonger: Yes but the demos and everything look like they are built specifically for mobile applications. Do I need to build a separate website with separate URL for desktop? I want the native look for desktop and mobile look to only come on mobile devices.

Comment: jQuery Mobile is more of a markup language -- it's really designed for mobile apps more than mobile websites, and for compatibility with iPhone, iPad, and Android all at once. jQuery-UI is a collection of widgets which are primarily designed for desktop browsers. You can still use jQuery and jQuery-UI with jQuery Mobile, but you probably shouldn't.

Comment: @Blazemonger: This line was the key: "it's really designed for mobile apps more than mobile websites". Thanks. That helped me to understand. Can you please say what is the approach I should use to display my website differently (normally) on desktop version and then it should switch to Jquery mobile look if it is being viewed in browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery Mobile is more of a markup language -- it's really designed for mobile apps more than mobile websites, and for compatibility with iPhone, iPad, and Android all at once. jQuery-UI is a collection of widgets which are primarily designed for desktop browsers. You can still use jQuery-UI with jQuery Mobile, but you probably shouldn't.

If you're just working with a basic website, then CSS media queries are the way to go. Google that exact phrase or [just start here](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).

If you still want to use jQuery Mobile, there are any number of ways to redirect mobile users from your public website to the mobile one. Probably the first one I would try is the least intrusive: add a link at the top directing users to the mobile website, and use the aforementioned CSS media queries to hide it from desktop users:

```
@media all and (min-width: 701px) {
    #link-to-mobile-site {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

This allows mobile visitors to continue using the full website whenever they want, gives them an easy-to-bookmark link when they don't, and creates a minimum of work for you.

Answer (score 1):

there are chances of conflict between the css of both Jquery and jquery mobile...moreover try to make it on jquery mobile since jquery mbl is specifically made for ipad/iphone and also looks neat on desktop

Comment: @tom yes u need to make a separate look for desktop and mbl as area available in desktop is much larger compared to iphone...try how youtube does....detect if its open on desktop open the url www.youtube.com or its opened on iphone open as m.youtube.com

Comment: I know what happens but I don't know "how" it happens. My question is for "how" it happens and how can I do that in my web application.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373010/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-whether-the-client-is-a-tablet-or-a-phone