# detect phone with script and not tablet

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to detect a mobile phone device as opposed to a tablet/desktop.
If I detect a mobile phone I will load a jquery mobile website.

is this the script from here to use as I dont know if this will also detect a mobile browser on a tablet.

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

I checked a post here where it mentions phone but not quite sure about tablet sizes?[What's the best way to detect whether the client is a tablet or a phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373010/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-whether-the-client-is-a-tablet-or-a-phone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ seems to detect only phones. I tried it on two different tablets and it said that "No mobile browser detected."